# Perform single AES-NI round in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I am writing AES for academic purpose only.

I would like to have methods like:

```
byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] data)
byte[] encryptFinal(byte[] key, byte[] data)
```

that uses AES-NI, to compare them with mine.
In other words, I do not want to perform full encryption with key expansion and specifying modus operandi - I want to feed stock algorithm with my data (including my expanded key) and perform just one round.

I see that AES-NI allows such approach 
( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set )
but how to invoke it from Java?

It would be great, if I could separate key expansion method too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look in at the **Java** implementation of **AES** in Bouncy Castle. You can find the latest release [here](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Download the Source version of the JCE with Provider (e.g. bcprov-jdk15on-154.zip) and find the AESEngine.java)

Comment: I do not see AES-NI used in this implementation. By AES-NI I mean (properly wrapper for Java of course) assember instruction